# Python Spacing Between Print Calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to make the spacing between print statements the same. I thought that the spacing would be the same but between the third and fourth lines of text there is a larger gap.

Here is my code

```
    import random
    import time

    def UserInfo():
        UserName = input ("Player 1 what is your name?\n")
        return UserName

    def Introduction(UserName):
        time.sleep(.5)
        print ("Hello " + UserName + ",\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("You are an unfortunate soul\n")

    UserName = UserInfo()
    Introduction(UserName)
```

The result i am getting is

```
    Player 1 what is your name?
    Patrick
    Hello Patrick,

    You are an unfortunate soul
```

But I dont want the gap between the third and fourth lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want extra linebreaks, don't use extra `\n`s. `print` adds a line feed by default.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a newline in the line

> print ("Hello " + UserName + ",\n")

since print adds automatically a new line

Answer (score 0):

print will by default add the newline.

If you want to control the newline completely by yourself, you can add a "," behind. This will let python stop to add the newline automatically.

For example:

```
print ("Hello " + UserName + ",\n"),
```